# Continuous function at a point characterized by sequences

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $X$ is a sequential space. If $Y$ is a topological space, it is proven in Engelking that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous (on the whole space) if and only if for each sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $X$ converging to a point $x\in X$ the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $Y$ converges to $f(x)$.

But I cannot imagine the condition in terms of sequences for a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ ($X$ and $Y$ as before) to be continuous **only** at a point $a\in X$. I started supposing that the necessary and sufficient condition for that is that for any sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $X$ converging to $a$, the sequences $\{f(x_n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $Y$ converges to $f(a)$. If $f$ is continuous it is obvious that the condition holds. But I don't know how to prove that such a condition is enough (if it is, that is not clear).

By definition, I would have to prove that for each neighbourhood $U'$ of $f(a)$, there is a neoghbourhood $U$ of $a$ such that $U\subseteq f^{-1}(U')$. I think, this condition is equivalent to prove that for any open set $V'$ containing $f(a)$, the set $f^{-1}(V')$ contains $a$ and is open too. Since $X$ is sequential, I will be done if I'm able to prove that $f^{-1}(U')$ is sequentially open. Or that the complement of $f^{-1}(U')$ in $X$, $f^{-1}(Y\setminus U')$ is sequentially closed. But I don't know how. The problem is that those definitions imply sequences with different limits, but I know that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(a)$ **only when** $x_n$ converges to $a$.

So that:

1.- What is the characterization in terms of sequences for a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ to be continuous when $X$ is sequential?

2.- In case that my condition was right, how can I prove the result?

Thanks.

**Remark.** Notice that I'm not supposing $X$ to be Hausdorff.

EDIT

Following hamamAbdallah's advice, I think I can give a proof. Suppose that $f$ is sequentially continuous but not continuous. By definition, there exists a neighbourhood $U'$ of $f(a)$ such that there is no $U$ neighborhood of $a$ satisfying $f(U)\subseteq U'$. The idea now is define s sequence that converges to $a$ but that its image does not converge to $f(a)$.  For each neighbourhood of $a$, call $A_U=f(U)\setminus U'$. Consider a net $(x_U)$, where $x_U\in f^{-1}(A_U)$. This net converges to $a$. I claim that since $X$ is sequential, I can pick a subnet of $(x_U)$ that is a sequence and that also converges to $a$. Call it $(x_n)_n$. But by definition of $A_U$, the sequence $(f(x_n))_n$ should not be able to converge to $f(a)$, which is a contradiction.

Is this proof valid? How can I justify that the subnet I claimed actually exists?

Comment: Assume $f$ not continuous and construct a sequence which ...

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah OK. I'm going to try. Thanks.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Can you give a clue about how to construct such a sequence, please?

Comment: I think I know how I can construct the sequence. I'll add an edit to my question tomorrow. Thanks again @hamam_Abdallah.

Comment: My guess of an opinion: sequential spaces not necessarily being first-countable is more of a problem than not being Hausdorff (every metric space is first-countable and Hausdorff).

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah is there any reason we should expect to not have $M$ an open neighborhood of $f(a)$ such that $f^{-1}(M)$ is not open but the only sequence converging to some $p \in f^{-1}(M)$ that is not eventually in $f^{-1}(M)$ converges to some $p$ different from $a$?
I am feeling kind of anxious about what I said, unless you have something to say here then I think $X$ not necessarily being first-countable is at issue.

Comment: @hamamAbdallah I have added an edit to my question. Please have a look at. Thanks.

Comment: You can have a net, but there need not be a subnet that is a sequence... maybe in a Fréchet-Urysohn space instead of a sequential one.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Then, how do you prove the result?

Comment: @Dog_69 why do you even think it’s true?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma 
I don't know. I asked the question and in his comment, I think hamamAbdallah gave me the reason. Anyway. My question says that if that characterization is not true, what is the correct?

Comment: I think hamam was of the impression that an argument to the effect of: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sequential_Continuity_is_Equivalent_to_Continuity_in_Metric_Space would apply. As I explained, it doesn't seem to unless X is assumed first-countable. Seems like the answer to your question is that there is a reason this Engelking person proves the statement you describe and not the one you are further interested in.

Comment: @MattAPelto OK. It seems that being seq. continuous only at a point is a very weak property. A nice answer would be a counterexample swhowing this fact or another condition for $f$ keeping the space sequential but not 1AN.

Comment: I agree that a counterexample would be nice.

Comment: @MattAPelto I think I have a nice counterexample. I'll post an answer tomorrow.

Comment: I have added an answer with a counterexample. Please check it. Thanks

Comment: This post is inetresting: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138100/characterization-of-fr%C3%A9chet-urysohn-spaces-using-sequential-continuity-at-a-poin

Answer (score 1):

Here I present a counterexample to my question. I think I have find a function that is sequentially continuous at $a$, i.e. for any sequence $(x_n)_n$ on $X$ converging to $a$, the sequence $(f(x_n))_n$ converges to $f(a)$, but that $f$ is not continuous at $a$, i.e. there exists a neighbourhood of $f(a)$ such that there doesn't exist a neighbourhood of $a$ which image is contained into the first.

Let $X=\mathbb Z^+\cup\{\ast\}\cup(\mathbb Z^+\times\mathbb Z^+)$ be the Arens' space (see [here](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/a-note-about-the-arens-space/)) and let $Y$ be the real line. Consider a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ defined as follows:

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1/x, & \mbox{if } x\in\mathbb Z^+ \\
0, & \mbox{if } x=\ast \\
m^n, &\mbox{if } x=(m,n)\in\mathbb Z^+\times\mathbb Z^+ .
\end{cases}
$$

I claim that $f$ is sequentially continuous at $a=\ast$. Indeed, the unique sequences that converge to $\ast$ are $x_n=n$ for $n\geq n_0$ or $x_n=\ast$ for $n\geq n_0'$. In the firts case we have that $f(x_n)=1/n$ while in the second and $f(x_n)=0$ (we are assuming $n_0=n_0'=0$). In both cases the sequences $(f(x_n))$ converge to $0$ in $Y$. However $f$ is not continuous at $a$: A neighbourhood of $\ast$ contains infinitely many isolated points $(m,n)$ which $f$ maps to big numbers $m^n$. Hence, for a neighbourhood say $V=(-1,1)$ of $0$, there is no $U$ neighbourhood of $\ast$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$.

**Remark.** Notice that this $f$ is not unique. We could set other functions $f$ with different values on $Z=\mathbb Z^+\times \mathbb Z^+$; for example that which is constant (different from $0$) on this subset. The important think here is that the set $f(Z)$ must be unbounded or have a positie infimum.

---

Let me give some details about the topology of $X$. In terms of neighbourhoods, the topology of $X$ is described as follows:

- Points belonging to the plane $\mathbb Z^+\times \mathbb Z^+$ are isolated.
- For positive integers $n$, a fundamental system of neighbourhoods is given by the set $\{B_m(n)\}_{m\in\mathbb N^*}$, where $B_m(n)$ consists in the point $n$ together with the $n$-th column, except the firts $m$ points. For example, $B_3(2)=\{2\}\cup\{(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),\dots\}$.
- And finally the point $\ast$. Neighbourhoods for it consists of the whole space $X$ minus finitely many $B_1(n)$ (i.e. some columns of the plane $\mathbb Z^+\times\mathbb Z^+$ together with the naturals that label such columns). And, in the resulting set, you are allow to remove also finite many points **of each** of the remaining columns (so can remove infinitely many in total).

Now, my first claim:

*The unique sequences that converge to $\ast$ are of the form $x_n=\ast$ for  $n\geq n_0$ or $x_n= n$ for $n\geq n_0'$.*

Well, it is clear that the above sequences converge to $\ast$ (the first is obvious and for the second, recall that neighbourhoods of $\ast$ have all but a finite number of $n\in\mathbb Z^+$). Now suppose that $(x_n)$ is a sequences on $X$ but is not of the above form. We can suppose that all the terms are isolated points. Now, if the sequence is eventually constant we can remove that point from a neighbourhood of $\ast$. And the result follows. If it is non-constant but all the points all contained in a column, we can remove that, and $\ast$ is not a limit neither. On the other hand, if the sequences is a row, since we were allowed to remove a finite quantity of points of each row, we can define a neighbourhood $V$ of $\ast$ such that $x_n\not\in V$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. And we are done, because there is no more convergent sequences on $X$.

Comment: I have some reservations about what you have said but I at least see what you are getting at by bringing up Arens' space. One issue is that I am a bit unclear on the def. in the article you linked. It seems to be a different topology but I have no issue understanding this topology proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Arens-Fort_Space. (0,0) poses just the sort of problem one might expect by merely assuming X is a sequential space. I am not saying the function won't be continuous, but I know why the argument that has been alluded to won't follow and (0,0) in the Arens-Fort space is just the point.

Comment: @MattAPelto: The Arens' space has been discussed in this site. I hope you can find some post with a nice explanation. And regarding my example, maybe some other experimented users can give a reason why it is/isn't correct.

Comment: I can't tell you why you don't have a counterexample (I mean, unless I study the article you linked and what you said more carefully). Like I say, I merely expect an example of why the alluded to proof by contradiction doesn't follow. Suppose $f$ is a real-valued function on the AF space ($X$) such that $f$ is sequentially continuous at $(0,0) \in X$. Assume towards a contradiction that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$. Can you consider why this proposed proof by contradiction doesn't exactly follow in this context? Note: No sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ can converge to $(0,0)$

Comment: *doesn't follow when $X$ is sequential but not assumed first-countable.

Comment: While I am still unsure about your definition of $f$, notice the preimage of $V$ under $f$ cannot contain these points you are concerned about (definition of the preimage). So your logic doesn't exactly follow in showing that $f$ is **not** continuous, it more alludes to the fact that you probably shouldn't hope to show that $f$ is continuous (in the non-sequential sense). If you edit the claims in your answer, then I would be willing to upvote because I do appreciate your response leading me to the Arens-Fort space.

Comment: What you said seems particularly unclear about the sequences that converge to $*$ and the definition of $f$

Comment: @MattAPelto: First of all, I appreciate the interest that you have in my question and in my answer. I'm going to edit the question to explain the Arens' space, the function and why I say that $f$ is sequentially continuous at $\ast$ but not continuous. On the other hand, if you have a counterexample on the Arens-Fort space, please feel fre to post an answer. If I understand it, I suppose I will accept it. Finally, if you want to continue the disucussion in the chat it's ok for me.

Comment: @MattAPelto There was a few little mistakes on the body of the answer. Maybe there were confusing you. I have added extra information too.